# ¿Por qué no se me otorga la etiqueta de Taxónomo si yo edité su wiki?

Tags: soporte, estado-por-diseño, medallas, wiki-de-etiqueta

¿Es posible que exista algun tipo de bug a la hora de otorgar la medalla [Taxónomo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)? O quizás yo no entienda cómo se otorga.

Tomando como ejemplo la primera se le otorgó a Konamiman ♦, resulta que esa etiqueta la creé yo. Bueno, si se puede decir así... jaja casualidad que la primera de la lista [la creé yo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/22/revisions).

Si tomamos la segunda un tanto de lo mismo: el usuario que [la creó](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164/revisions) no es al que se le otorgó.

La tercera sí es curiosa porque César sí aparece como que la editó pero según entiendo [la creó Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/658/revisions) así que no sé qué criterios se aplican para otrogar la medalla.

---

## Respuesta

Creo que es lo que dejé en [el comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/505/por-qu%C3%A9-no-se-me-otorga-la-etiqueta-de-tax%C3%B3nomo-si-yo-edit%C3%A9-su-wiki#comment1208_505):

> ahh espera que igual se refiera con crear, al que la escribe en el
>   lugar para añadir los tag en las preguntas por primera vez y esta no
>   existe, y no al que crea la definicion del tag cuando esta no existe,
>   bueno se me acaba de ocurrir que quizas sea eso, yo lo dejo por aqui,
>   porque puede ser que sea eso en lo que se basan para lo de Taxónomo.
>   Saludos

Se basan en el que usa la etiqueta por primera vez, no en quien edita su página wiki.

Para confirmar, acabo de mirar la [primera pregunta de angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/8/83) y fue realizada por Konamiman ♦ y fue él mismo quien [añadió la etiqueta angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8/1).

Comment: jaja iba a coger la de César como ejemplo pero, como no tengo nada contra el digo, pues por orden y resulta que salgo en la primera jaja. Saludos

Comment: ahh espera que igual se refiera con crear, al que la escribe en el lugar para añadir los tag en las preguntas por primera vez y esta no existe, y no al que crea la definicion del tag cuando esta no existe, bueno se me acaba de ocurrir que quizas sea eso, yo lo dejo por aqui, porque puede ser que sea eso en lo que se basan para lo de Taxónomo. Saludos

Comment: correcto, hay varios post en meta que lo explican, el autor de un tag es el primero en usarla en una pregunta. Incluso si el tag es eliminado, y vuelto a crear la medalla la recibe el creador original. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/who-is-the-creator-of-a-tag-for-taxonomist-purposes)

Comment: es confuso, yo pensé quedebía recibir la medalla de taxonomo por  [tag:c#] pero no.

Comment: Interesante Angel Angel, sugiero mover el Update a la zona de respuestas, pues tú mismo te respondiste :)